# How can I make a VBS Message Box appear in a random place?

Tags: vbscript, messagebox

In VBS script, I have created a simple message box application. It currently stays in front of all windows until the user responds and uses very simple coding

```
    X=MsgBox("Test Text" ,1+4069, "Test Title")
```

But it always appears in the same place. Is there any way of making it appear in a random place on the screen? Please help!

Comment: 4096 is the flag not 4069.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSGBOX position in WSH/VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990022/msgbox-position-in-wsh-vbs)

Comment: Thanks for that. Might explain why some of them didnt work

Comment: It isn't exactly a duplicate. That was a set position. I want it to be a RANDOM position.

Comment: Plus,that is using InputBox. I am trying to use MessageBox

Answer (score 0):

There is one type of box which allows you to position it on the screen: **[InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

```
Title = "Hello"
DefaultValueText = "Hello Stackoverflow !"
message = "Type something here"
XPos = 0
YPos = 0
Text = InputBox(message,Title,DefaultValueText,XPos,YPos)
XPos = 3000
YPos = 800
Text = InputBox(message,Title,DefaultValueText,XPos,YPos)
```

Comment: So, should I put * for random?

Answer (score 0):

@Hackoo was almost there,
I used his and here is what I made out of it.

```
dim r
randomize
r = int(rnd*500) + 1
r2 = int(rnd*1500) + 1
Title = "Hello"
DefaultValueText = "Hello!"
message = "Type something here!"
XPos = r
YPos = r2
Text = InputBox(message,Title,DefaultValueText,XPos,YPos)
```

Comment: Oh also, you wont see much difference, if you spam it, you will see something short.